# Oracle conversion causes error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01481

Can anyone explain what is wrong with this SQL?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1890.55,'$9,99D9V99') FROM DUAL;
```

it throws an error:

> ORA-01481: invalid number format model
>   01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model
>   Cause: The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has supplied an invalid number format model parameter.
>   Action: Consult your manual.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You are more likely to get an answer if we know what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string doesn't specify enough digits to the left of the decimal specifier (`D`) for the number you've given. In addition, you can't mix `,` and `D` formatting characters in the same format string, *and* you can't have more than one of `V` or `D` or `.` in a format string. You can either use

```
$9,999.99
```

or

```
$9G999D99
```

or

```
$9,999V99
```

although the last one, obviously, won't show a decimal point.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
select to_char(1890.55,'fm$999G990D00','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') from dual
```